# 19.10 installation media cannot access internal SSD (Dell Inspiron 15 5000)

Tags: system-installation, dell, ssd, 19.10, inspiron

I’ve just bought a new Dell laptop and created a USB Drive with the 19.10 installation media on it.
However, upon entering setup, the only install location recognised is the USB Drive, and is the first drive recognised in the computer (sda1.)
Same applies with the .iso burned to a DVD on a USB DVD drive.
Could there be a UEFI Setting blocking access to the internal NVMe M.2 SSD?
(Secure Boot is disabled.)

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what I did, but I disabled RAID and I can now access the SSD. Please mark as closed. (I don’t know how myself.)